# Disable reviews and rating after or before the app is released from the Apple App Store?

Tags: app-store, release, publish, rating, iosdeployment

i just want to ask a quick question after a long search i haven't found an answer regarding this topic.
in fact is there a way for a developer to disable reviews and rating after or before the app is released to the App Store , just for a very short time ?
this solution exists in Google Play, but I found some information in the internet I think it's not possible for App Store.
What do you think guys ?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible on iOS/the App Store. You can only choose to reset the rating with a new version - that's it.